# Using extension methods within inline databinding context

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, extension-methods

I'm trying to use some extension methods that I use to apply consistent formatting to DateTime and Int32 - which works absolutely fine in code behind, but I'm having issues with databinding.

I get:

```
'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'ToCustomShortDate'
```

for

```
<%# ((ProductionDetails)Container.DataItem).StartDate.ToCustomShortDate() %>
```

(inside a templatefield of a gridview contained on a usercontrol)

Even when I'm including the namespace that the extension method is defined in at the top of the usercontrol:

```
<%@ import namespace="MyAssembly.Formatting" %>
```

Has anyone else come across this and is there any way to resolve it?

**EDIT:** My mistake, above should be:

```
<%@ import namespace="MyNamespace.Formatting" %>
```

ie. I'm not incorrectly referencing the namespace (works vertabim in the code behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue! I was including the namespace correcly as I thought - but the real issue was that the app was only INCLUDING the .NET 3.5 assemblies and not being compiled using the 3.5 compiler, was missing some entries from web.config which I realised when I created an empty project and tried it (successfully) in there!

Error messages can be so misleading sometimes...

Comment: I ended up with this same issue. Had to right-click on the Project, go to the 'Application' tab, and switch the runtime to .NET 4.0.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the extenstion method i implemented above should my namespace look like this?

```
namespace MyNamespace.Formatting
```

Comment: Yes it should - they match, it just doesnt seem to be getting picked up.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the assembly name from the import namespace...

I guess your extension method is located in an namespace called Formatting.

```
namespace Formatting
{

    public static class DateTimeExtender
    {
        public static string ToCustomShortDate(this DateTime date)
        {
            return date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
        }
    }

    public class ProductionDetails
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

And in the ASPX page...

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Formatting" %>
```